# Java console app jar - Handle Exception and continue in windows command prmpt

Tags: java, windows, cmd, java-console

I have a Console Java Application in maven, infinite loop

I have handle exception in java

```
  public class MyClassName {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            while (true) {
                start();
            }
        }

        private static void start() {
            try {
                //this method check new files in S3 and copy to network location also it has throws Throwable
                //i have not added code here because it is too long
                doProcess()
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

doProcess() method check new files in  S3 and copy to Network Machine
also it has **throws Throwable**

after creating jar, in windows command promp

```
java -jar -Xmx8192M jarname.jar
```

when it throws exception, pause completely until **ctrl+C**, but if I **ctrl+C** it will resume again,

what is wrong here? 
is there any wrong on java code or is there any wrong on command?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: run the application without pausing?

Comment: But that couldn't be the real goal of the application. Why are you using while(true)? Even the code snippet is missing a closing bracket after the t.printStackTrace. Is there code missing?

Comment: doProcess() method check new file in  S3 and copy to Network Machine, The java code is just an example I will add bracket just to clear